# Requirement Quality Widget Issue for Automated Tests

Tags: testing, azure-devops, automation, automated-tests

This is forwarded from [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/requirement-quality-widget-issue-for-automated-tes/549367), originally posted by [kamalakannan G](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/user/fe26ef9c-d111-63b0-8722-66261c950791/profile).  After several hours of experimentation, I happened to find something of a workaround.  The original question is closed, so posting here in case others need it.

(I am using Azure DevOps Server Version Dev18.M170.6, so there's a good chance this is fixed in the latest version, but this is what I currently have to work with.)

> **[kamalakannan G](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/user/fe26ef9c-d111-63b0-8722-66261c950791/profile)**
>
> Requirement Quality widget is displaying as "No Linked Tests" when Automated Tests from Tests tab of release is linked to user Stories through "Link" option in Tests tab. Automated Tests are displayed under "NotAssociated" when filtered by Requirements. Widget gets updated when Test Result links are removed from User Story.

Not exactly a question, granted.  If I were to superimpose my own, it would perhaps be something like "Associating test results to requirements is broken.  Is there a workaround?"  I have provided my answer below using the Q&A feature, but certainly if anyone else knows of a better solution I'd gladly hear it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, such as it is, was initially inspired by one of the [comments](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/requirement-quality-widget-issue-for-automated-tes/549367#T-N1272935) to the above original question:

> **[Stephen Skinner](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/user/7adbbd4e-b87d-6061-b384-c97266eefce0/profile)**
>
> My company recently upgraded from TFS 2018 to DevOps Server 2019, and have found this functionality mostly broken in both versions. It will always link to a requirement, but the link it creates is incorrect the majority of the time. This causes the Requirement Quality Widget to not work properly. It also causes the Tests tab of the build or release to not work properly as well, when grouping tests by requirements. Linking to a new or existing bug appears to always link correctly, but seldom does it update a requirement with the proper link.
>
> When it works, the requirement will show the test name under Test on the links tab. When you hover over the test, the correct URL to the test will be displayed, such as:
>
> https://tfsenterprise.company.com/tfs/Collection/Project/_TestManagement/Runs?_a=contribution&runId=72054&resultId=100000&selectedGroupBy=group-by-branch&contributionId=ms.vss-test-web.test-result-history
>
> When the link is created properly with the URL, everything works as expected. This however rarely occurs when linking to requirements.
>
> What usually happens, at least for my company, is that the requirement shows a linked test as : vstfs:///TestManavement/TcmTest/12345
>
> In this case, you can't group results by requirements as they will all show as not linked, even though it shows the requirement under "Requirements" of the test. This also causes the quality widget to show "No Linked Tests" for the requirements that were linked in this way.

The description of the improperly linked test was consistent with my own attempts.  Since it appeared linking to bugs did work correctly for Mr. Skinner, I decided to try doing that to see if I got further similar results.  The bug link did work, so I took it a step further.  Changing the bug to a requirement (User Story in my case) did in fact retain the properly linked test results.  The test links were formatted correctly, and more to the point, the Requirements Quality widget now showed the links' results.

So the workaround, as I currently have it, is to simply change the requirement to a bug type before linking test results to it, and of course to change it back to a requirement thereafter.  Tedious, but stable so far.  I haven't tested yet with creating a bug from the test result link, though I imagine that should work as well and might reduce some of the changing types; although I don't expect to do it that way very much, since (ideally) I'll be creating requirements before having test results to associate with them.